# How to make <mat-table> responsive like as child rows as DataTable have : Angular

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I want `<mat-table>` responsive like as DataTable with child rows (https://datatables.net/). Like when we check in mobile size then some rows hide and will be in child rows with expandable view.

Comment: There's an issue regarding this topic on the official Angular Material2 GitHub repo: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8494

Comment: So can you please provide me any other solution if you have ? Btw thank you for reply..